# sklearn: 'bool' object has no attribute 'any'

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest, sklearn-pandas, gridsearchcv

I'm building a pipeline and then using GridSearchCV to determine the best parameters. However, when I use the pipe object, I keep getting the error: 'bool' object has no attribute 'any'
Below is a snippet of my code. Also, GridSearchCV can only be used the find the best params and then I have to create a new model with the best params and use that to predict OR is there a better way around this?

```
column_trans = make_column_transformer((OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore'),['violation_street_name','zip_code', 'violation_code','disposition']),
                                       remainder= 'passthrough')
column_trans.fit_transform(X)

# ------------------------------ Finding the best classifier ---------------------------------

rf = RandomForestClassifier()
params = {'randomforestclassifier__n_estimators':[10,20,50,100], 'randomforestclassifier__max_depth':[3, 5, 7, 10]}


pipeline = make_pipeline(column_trans, rf)
grid = GridSearchCV(pipeline, param_grid= params, cv=5)

cm = cross_val_score(pipe, X, y, cv=3, scoring='accuracy', n_jobs=-1)
print(cm)

grid.fit(X,y)
print(grid.best_params_)

# ---------------------------- end of finding the best classifier ------------------------------------

# -------------------------- define new pipeline with best params ------------------------------------
rfbest = RandomForestClassifier(max_depth=3, n_estimators=10)
pipelinebest = make_pipeline(column_trans, rfbest)

bfit = pipelinebest.fit(X,y)
print(bfit)
y_proba_lr = bfit.predict(X_test)
y_proba_list = list(zip(X_test['ticket_id'][0:20], y_proba_lr[0:20,1]))
print(y_proba_list)
```